# How do I detect when a specific character is put in the input?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group"><label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="s1">URL</label>
                <div class="col-md-4"><input id="url" name="url" type="text" ng-change="checkVal()" ng-model="url" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md"></div>
            </div>
```

**Javascript v1.6**

```
 var app = angular.module('urlGeneratorAvid', [])

  .controller('macroControllerAvid',['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.needQuestionMark = true;
    $scope.url = '';

    $scope.checkVal = function() {
      console.log("Checking Value.");
      if ($scope.url.includes('?')) {
        console.log("Detected!");
        $scope.needQuestionMark = false;
        console.log("Question Mark Variable: " + $scope.needQuestionMark);
      } else {
        $scope.needQuestionMark = true;
        console.log("Question Mark Variable: " + $scope.needQuestionMark);
      }
    }

  }]);
```

**The Goal**

Manipulate the variable **needQuestionMark** from the directive. It currently outputs the correct data from the directive, but I can't seem to manipulate it.

**Ultimate Goal**

Detect of the URL input contains a question mark so the full URI does not contain a second question mark but instead an ampersand.

New to AngularJS so, if I'm going in the wrong direction, let me know, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I get you 100%.

To detect and operate on ngModel/input value. You don't have to use directive for it.

Good idea is to put watch inside controller, like so

```
$scope.$watch('$scope.textBox', function(newValue, oldValue) {
   // do stuff to the text everytime it changes
});
```

Second option can be adding ng-change to html

[ng-change example](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_ng-change)

Third. Do component for it, it's like a directive but a new way of working with Angular.

[Components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)

Also about your controller. Try to use controller as. Below some usefull staff to fallow : )

[Angular style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md)

Comment: Okay, just a quick update here. I didn't know a directive wasn't mandatory for using $scope.watch(), learned something new today, haha. I'm currently working on my code and just wanted to know what I was missing that confused you so i can make sure my question is more clear.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out, based on your second option, ng-change. I updated the question with the source code to match against your answer, to help people figure it out later on. Thank you!

Comment: That is very kind of you!

Good luck with your core : )